# Responsive table with headings on the left (vertical)

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to build a responsive table. So far so easy. Therefore I used the following [CodePen by Dudley Sturey](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/Geprd):

```
*CSS (Pen rewritten for SAAS)*
table.responsive-table {
    margin: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    font-weight: 100; 
    background: #333; color: #fff;
    text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
    border-radius: 5px; 

    caption { 
        font-size: 2rem; color: #fff;;
        margin: 1rem;
        background-size: contain;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-position: center left, center right; 
    }

    thead th { font-weight: 600; }
    thead th, tbody td { padding: .8rem; font-size: 1.4rem; }
    tbody td { padding: .8rem; font-size: 1.4rem; color: #444; background: #eee; }
    tbody tr:not(:last-child) { border-top: 1px solid #ddd; border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd; }

    @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {

        caption { background-image: none; }
        thead { display: none; }
        tbody td { display: block; padding: .6rem; }
        tbody tr td:first-child { background: #666; color: #fff; }
        tbody td:before { content: attr(data-th); font-weight: bold; display: inline-block; width: 6rem; }

    }
}

*HTML*
    <table class="responsive-table">
        <caption>The Films of Hayao Miyazaki</caption>
        <thead align="left">
            <tr><th>Film</th><th>Year</th><th>Honor</th></tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>My Neighbor Totoro</td>
                <td>1988</td>
                <td>Blue Ribbon Award (Special)</td>
            </tr>    
            <tr>
                <td>Princess Mononoke</td>
                <td>1997</td>
                <td>Nebula Award (Best Script)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Spirited Away</td>
                <td>2001</td>
                <td>Academy Award (Best Animated Feature)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Howl’s Moving Castle</td>
                <td>2004</td>
                <td>Hollywood Film Festival (Animation OTY)</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

Which indeed is a wonderful piece of code. My problem now is, that I'd like to have the table headings on the left side of the table. I googled around a bit and found like ... well, nearly nothing. The only way stated was without using  and  tags, but those are mandatory for usage with the pen made by Dudley.

Does anybody have an idea how to achieve Headings on the Left with `thead` any `tbody` tags?

Thank you very much for your time and assistance in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

Just give left align to your table headers:

```
 thead{
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: That does not do what I want. I mean I want the heading to be on the left side of the table like Okay obviously linebreaks are not displayed in comments. I wrote a <br /> to illustrate.

*heading* _bla_  _bla_  _bla_<br />
*heading* _bla_  _bla_  _bla_<br />
*heading* _bla_  _bla_  _bla_

Comment: Is the issue still persist ?